# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined on my Javascript Signup and Login Page

Tags: node.js, web-deployment

I have the following JavaScript code and I get an error that says:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Specifically, at the line: const parola=form.parola.value;

```js
<%- include('partials/header') %>

<form action="/signup">
    <h2>Kullanıcı Oluştur</h2>
    <label for="email">email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" required/>
    <div class="email error"></div>
    <label for="email">Parola</label>
    <input type="password" name="email" required/>
    <div class="password error"></div>
    <button type="submit">Oluştur</button>
</form>

<%- include('partials/footer') %>

<script>
    const form=document.querySelector('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit',async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

        const email=form.email.value;
        const parola=form.parola.value;
       // console.log(email,parola);

        try {
            const res=await fetch('/signup',{
                method:'POST',
                body:JSON.stringify({email,parola}),
                headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }


    });
</script>
```

Any advise?

Comment: Did you really write "fatch" instead of "fetch"?

Answer (score 0):

you can use FormData :

```
<form action="/signup">
    <h2>Kullanıcı Oluştur</h2>
    <label for="email">email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" required/>
    <div class="email error"></div>
    <label for="email">Parola</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" required/>
    <div class="password error"></div>
    <button type="submit">Oluştur</button>
</form>

<script>

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log('Object.fromEntries(formData)', Object.fromEntries(formData));
  return Object.fromEntries(formData); 
}


const form=document.querySelector('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit',async (e)=>{
        var formData = handleSubmit(e);
 
    
        try {
            const res=await fetch('/signup',{
                method:'POST',
                body:JSON.stringify(formData),
                headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
 

    });
</script>
```

Working Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/cse20x61/3/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the result of `document.querySelector` is an `HTMLElementObject` so if you want your email you should do this:

```
form.querySelector('input[name=email]').value
```